# Mapping from pointers-to-member

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

<sup>(Note: in case this feels like an X-Y problem, scroll below the separator for how I arrived at this question)</sup>

I am looking for a way to store pointers-to-member-functions (of different types) and compare them for equality. I need to store a mapping from pointer-to-member-function to an arbitrary object, and then search this mapping. It doesn't have to be an associative container, a linear search is fine. Also note that the pointers serve as mapping keys only, they are never dereferenced.

My current approach is this: when building the mapping, I `reinterpret_cast` the incoming pointer-to-member to one well-known type (`void (MyClass::*)()`) and insert it into the mapping. Something like this (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
template <class R, class... A)
void CallChecker::insert(R (MyClass::*key)(A...), Object value)
{
  mapping.push_back(std::make_pair(reinterpret_cast<void (MyClass::*)()>(key), value));
}
```

Then on lookup, I perform the same cast and search by equality:

```
template <class R, class... A)
Object CallChecker::retrieve(R (MyClass::*key)(A...)) const
{
  auto k = reinterpret_cast<void (MyClass::*)()>(key);
  auto it = std::find_if(begin(mapping), end(mapping), [k](auto x) { return x.first == k; });
  return it->second;
}
```

However, I am not sure that this will always work. While I believe it cannot produce false negatives (two equal pointers being reported as distinct), I am afraid it might produce false negatives (two pointers which were originally of different type could compare equal when cast to the "common" type). So my question is, is that the case? Or am I safe in using comparisons like this?

I know I am treading dangerously close to UB territory here. However, I don't mind a solution which works using behaviour which is not defined by the standard, but known to work in gcc and MSVC (my two target compilers).

So, the question is: is the comparison in a common type safe? Or would I be better off casting the stored pointer to the incoming type for the comparison (like this):

```
template <class R, class... A)
Object CallChecker::retrieve(R (MyClass::*key)(A...)) const
{
  auto it = std::find_if(begin(mapping), end(mapping), [key](auto x) { return reinterpret_cast<R (MyClass::*)(A...)>(x.first) == key; });
  return it->second;
}
```

Or will neither of these work in practice and I'm out of luck?

---

I am interested in the above properties of pointers-to-member, both in light of my actual task and to deepen my understanding of the language. Still, out of a sense of completeness (and in case somebody knows a better way), here is how I arrived at the original question.

I'm building a utility framework for helping unit-testing **Qt4** signals (testing that the proper signals are emitted). My idea was to create a class `CallChecker` that would store validators (wrapped `std::function` objects) for slots, and be able to run them. The test would then create a class derived from this; that class would define slots which would run the corresponding validators. Here's an idea of usage (simplified):

```
class MyTester : public QObject, public CallChecker
{
  Q_OBJECT
public slots:
  void slot1(int i, char c) { CallChecker::checkCall(&MyTester::slot1, i, c); }
  void slot2(bool b) { CallChecker::checkCall(&MyTester::slot2, b); }
};

void testRunner()
{
  MyTester t;
  connectToTestedSignals(t);
  t.addCheck(&MyTester::slot1, [](int i, char c) { return i == 7; });
}
```

I have a [working implementation](http://ideone.com/NrfRSk) (gcc on ideone) where `CallChecker` uses a `std::vector` of pairs, with the pointers-to-member cast to a common function type. After some fiddling with compiler flags (`/vmg`), I got this working in MSVC as well.

If you can suggest a better solution than lookup by pointer to member, I'll be happy to hear it. My goal is ease of use in the class implementing the test slots: I really want these slots to be simple one-liners. Using a textual representation of the slot signature (what Qt uses internally) is not really an option, as it's too susceptible to typos.

Comment: Why would anyone need to do such thing? This is a x-y problem, as unit testing qt signal-slots is done differently. I could answer how is it done properly, but I can not answer your question.

Comment: "Also note that the pointers serve as mapping keys only, they are never dereferenced." Type erasure than ? Something like `boost::any` kind of types ?

Comment: @BЈовић Please do, I even ask so in the question: "If you can suggest a better solution than lookup by pointer to member, I'll be happy to hear it."

Comment: If the 'X' is QT, this is not interesting to me. The 'Y' concerning what you can legitimately do with a pointer to member function is severely constrained by the standard, and in practice I think.

Comment: @david.pfx OK, I may have worded it ambiguously. I am primarily asking about the pointer-to-member part (also out of curiosity for the standardese aspect of it). Still, I wanted to put it into perspective of how I arrived at the problem. I've edited the question a bit, hopefully the focus is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first check that the `typeid` of both sides are the same, you can then use a type-erased function to cast both sides to the same type and compare in that type.  (This is strictly necessary by the standard, as even if you can round-trip via a well-known type, there is no guarantee by the standard that comparisons in that type will have the same behaviour as comparisons in the original type.)  Here's a sketch:

```
struct any_pmf_compare {
    std::type_index ti;
    void (any_pmf_compare::*pmf)();
    bool (*comp)(const any_pmf_compare &, const any_pmf_compare &);
    template<typename F>
    any_pmf_compare(F f):
        ti(typeid(F)),
        pmf(reinterpret_cast<void (any_pmf_compare::*)()>(f)),
        comp([](const any_pmf_compare &self, const any_pmf_compare &other) {
            return reinterpret_cast<F>(self.pmf) == reinterpret_cast<F>(other.pmf);
        })
    {
    }
};
bool operator==(const any_pmf_compare &lhs, const any_pmf_compare &rhs) {
    return lhs.ti == rhs.ti && lhs.comp(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very close to what I ended up doing, following the comment from @user2485710.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is guaranteed to work. The standard does not guarantee that two pointers-to-member-function will compare equal, regardless of how you get about doing it. My suggestion is to use the typeid itself, not the value of the pointer.

Comment: @david.pfx it does if *they would refer to the same member* (5.10p2). The following example is pretty clear that this is intended to work for pointers to member functions as well as pointers to data members.

Comment: @ecatmur: not on my reading. The full quote is //if they would refer to the same member of the same most derived object// and a function is not an object (S1.8). In the example (N3337) the comparison eventually yields false, but it is not obvious why that should be so. This may be a flaw in the standard, but at least it does not guarantee explicitly that two pointers-to-function will ever compare equal.

Comment: @david.pfx the standard says the *same member*, not the *same object*, so there's no requirement that the member be an object (it has to be a member *of an object*, but that's not the same thing). The standard isn't entirely consistent, but I think by the principle of charity we have to read "member" in that paragraph as referring to members in general, not only data members.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, there is a way to unit test that a qt signal is emitted. You need to use [QSignalSpy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalspy.html) and link to QTestLib.

As they say in their documentation :

> QSignalSpy can connect to any signal of any object and records its emission. QSignalSpy itself is a list of QVariant lists. Each emission of the signal will append one item to the list, containing the arguments of the signal.

You can also read their examples, but here is one of my unit tests that use google test :

```
class TestSomeControls : public testing::Test
{
public:

    TestSomeControls() :
        obj(),
        ctrl1Dis( &obj, SIGNAL(DisableControl1(bool)) ),
        ctrl2Dis( &obj, SIGNAL(DisableControl2(bool)) )
    {
    }

    model::SomeControls obj;

    QSignalSpy ctrl1Dis;
    QSignalSpy ctrl2Dis;
};

TEST_F( TestSomeControls, OnControl1Clicked_untilControl1Disabled )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i )
    {
        obj.OnControl1Clicked();
        ASSERT_EQ( ctrl1Dis.count(), 0 );
    }

    obj.OnControl1Clicked();

    ASSERT_EQ( ctrl1Dis.count(), 1 );
    ASSERT_EQ( ctrl1Dis.takeFirst().at(0).toBool(), true );
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Does this work for signal argument types which are not Qt metatypes?

Comment: @Angew No, because it has to be stored in QVariant. That is the one that requires it.

Comment: Oh well, back to the drawing board. Still, I'll keep this in mind for future use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Compare anything to anything.

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
  virtual bool operator== (const Base& other) const = 0;
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

template <class T>
struct Holder : Base
{
  Holder(T t) : t(t) {}
  bool operator== (const Base& other) const
  {
    const Holder<T>* h = dynamic_cast<const Holder<T>*>(&other);
    return (h && h->t == t);
  }
  private:
  T t;
};

struct Any
{
  template<class T>
    Any(T t) : p(std::make_shared<Holder<T>>(t)) {}
  bool operator== (const Any& other) const
  {
    return *p == *other.p;
  }
  private:
  std::shared_ptr<Base> p;
};

int main ()
{
  std::cout << (Any(2) == Any(2));
  std::cout << (Any(2) == Any(3));
  std::cout << (Any(2) == Any("foo"));
  std::cout << (Any("foo") == Any("foo"));
  std::cout << (Any("foo") == Any("bar"));
}
```

Implementation of `operator<` is deferred to the reader.

**Important note** Two pointers-to-member of different types will always compile unequal in this implementation, but it is possible that they will be equal in direct comparison after coercion to a common type. I.e `&Foo::x` and `&Bar::x` can be the same if `Foo` derives from `Bar`. Such behaviour cannot be easily added here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a narrow answer to the narrow question.

The standard states by implication and also in a footnote that a pointer to member cannot be converted to void*. The likely rationale is that a pointer to member could require more bytes of storage than a void*. Your compiler should forbid the reinterpret cast, and even it if does not you run a real risk of clashes. You can test on your target compilers, but the risk remains.

The standard will permit you to convert a 'pointer to member of X of type T1' to 'pointer to member of Y of type T2' when T1 and T2 are both function types. In other words, your strategy is permitted as long as the common type is a pointer to member function. I think this is what you intended. S5.2.10/10 in N3337. It does not however guarantee that two such pointers will compare equal, in the way that it does for pointers to objects. For example, if the implementation includes an encoded 'this' pointer, it just won't work.

The standard will permit you to store the pointer to member in a union. You can provide a char[] member that is likely to be long enough, and you can use an assert on sizeof to make sure that it is. Provided it's a 'standard layout' type, accessing the value through the char[] should have guaranteed behaviour. Personally, I would try this just to find out how big those pointers actually are! But the problem about possible non-canonical values remains.

My third suggestion is that you use the typeid of the pointer-to-member-function instead of the pointer itself. Typeid can be applied to any expression -- if it's good enough for reinterpret_cast it's good enough for typeid -- and the resultant value should be unique to the type, not the instance.

After that I'm out of ideas. You might have to redefine/renegotiate the problem in a quest for other solutions.

Comment: I *am* actually doing the `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer-to-member-function type, and say so in the question. Good point with the union, but IIRR you can't legally read a different member than the one you've last written (standard layout structs have an exception). Not to mention the fact that there's no guarantee two equal pointers to member will be bitwise-equal.

Comment: You're right. Edited to reflect that, and added typeid option.